# CMIS integration with BPM

Tags: alfresco, business-process-management, documentum, cmis, opencmis

Could you please let me know, is it possible to integrate CMIS with BPM system? I know Pega BPM system can be integrated with CMIS. But I want to integrate CMIS with Workflows in Documentum or with Alfresco repository.  I do not find out any object type related to BMP that CMIS provides.

Kindly advice. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no API provided by CMIS that directly maps to the realm of workflows: all of the domain model and APIs are meant for document management.

That said, it's not impossible to establish some contracts between the BPM engine and your client application, so that workflow related informations (states, properties, workflow definitions, etc) will be mapped to the CMIS domain level entities, i.e. documents, properties, relationships and policies.

It's definitely not ideal, but as there's no direct workflow API in CMIS that's the only option you get.

Comment: Thanks skuro, I also found the same.

Answer (score 0):

I see this question is rather old but an actual answer may still be interesting. I have successfully tested the concept of making a Service Broker for K2 (http://www.k2.com/) that supports CMIS.

K2 allows you building Service Brokers in .Net so this is rather simple. You can later on generate K2 SmartObjects connecting to your broker and use them in both your process and your web forms.

I actually tested this with Alfresco to test CMIS. The Alfresco support was great.

So to answer your question, yes, this is definitely possible with K2 Blackpearl and K2 SmartForms.